# Plot with manipulate

Tags: plotting, differential-equations, gr

I want to use appropriately use the Manipulate command in conjunction with Plot, to construct animated graphics for the evolution of the solution. I have tried but i could not succed to solve it

$f(x)=y_1(x)+0.2y_4(x)+0.01y_6(x)$.

$y_n$ are the Eigenfunctions that defined as $y_n(x)=\exp\left(\displaystyle{\frac{-x^2}{2}}\right)H_n(x)$

````
Her[n_] := HermiteH[n, x]
Y[n_] := Exp[-x^2/2]*Her[n]
Y[1]
Y[4]
Y[6]
f[x_] = Y[1] + 0.2 Y[4] + 0.01 Y[6]
```
````

Comment: Your function `eigen[n_]` is not used anywhere? So why is it there?

Comment: I have changed it. I have only defined the eigenvalues

Comment: Your $f(x)$ is fixed. So it does not change? But you can see how $y_n(x)$ changes with $n$ as shown below. Otherwise you need to clarify how $f(x)$ changes.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I assume you want to plot $y_n(x)$  as your $f(x)$ does not change? It is always better to pass all the parameters along to all the functions, (i.e. $n,x$) in this example. Do not pass somethings, say $n$, and leave others global (say $x$). This is a recipe for bugs when your program gets larger.

[image]

```
her[x_Symbol, n_Integer] := HermiteH[n, x]
Y[x_Symbol, n_Integer] := Exp[-x^2/2]*her[x, n]
f[x_Symbol, n_Integer] := Y[x, 1] + 2/10* Y[x, 4] + 1/100* Y[x, 6];
Manipulate[
 Module[{x},
  Plot[Evaluate@Y[x, n], {x, 0, 5}, 
   PlotRange -> {Automatic, {-30, 30}}, PlotLabel -> Row[{" Y_", n }],
    PlotStyle -> Red, GridLines -> Automatic, 
   GridLinesStyle -> LightGray]
  ],
 {{n, 0, "n"}, 0, 5, 1, Appearance -> "Labeled"},
 TrackedSymbols :> {n}
 ]
```